# Vue.js Router Query Array

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to do is pass an array from query to the backend using Vue.js and router.

So I have this method:

```
submitForm () {
  this.$router.push({
    name: 'AuctionResult',
    query: {
      models: this.selectedModels.map(e => e.value)
    }
  })
},
```

As a result will be query like this: `?models=MODEL1&models=MODEL2...`
But how can I make inputs look like array, like this: `?models[]=MODEL1&models[]=MODEL2...` ???

I didn`t find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To support PHP / array style multi-values, you can just set the key name to be what you want, ie

```
query: {
  'models[]': this.selectedModels.map(e => e.value)
}
```

This may come out as

```
?model%5B%5D=MODEL1&model%5B%5D=MODEL2...
```

but that's fine (it's just URL encoded) and your server-side request handler should decode it correctly.